# Stop printing of output when command is assingned to variable

Tags: shell

```
G1_P1=`$HOME/X/Y/Z/ test -i`;
```

It is printing the output of test -i 
Example:

```
$HOME/X/Y/Z/ test -i
```

Testing is done

I do not want the output to be shown. I want it to store to variable G1_P1 but without showing the output.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not stdout output that is getting printed in terminal. It is the output written on `stderr`. You can do this:

```
G1_P1=$($HOME/X/Y/Z/test -i 2>/dev/null)
```

to suppress stderr output.

Or if you want stderr output also in variable then use

```
G1_P1=$($HOME/X/Y/Z/test -i 2>&1)
```